# Mirroring the left side of a model's uvs so it's symmetrical to the right side

Tags: uv

I wish to make the left part of the UV match the right side of its' vertices placements and such (but mirrored) so they're symmetrical, I've tried many methods and different add ons, but I could never get any to work.[image]